# Internals visible to Boo (Binsor)

Tags: .net, clr, rhino-mocks, boo, binsor

I am using Castle Windsor for IoC and I want to use Binsor to define my configuration.
I want to let my internals be visible to Boo. I have tried to mark my assembly with 
`InternalsVisibleTo("Boo.Lang")` but that didn't do the job. I have tried `InternalsVisibleTo("Rhino.Commons")` because I have noticed that the exception is thrown from within Rhino.Commons.Binsor.BooComponentInstaller but that doesn't work neither. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

InternalsInvisible isn't available yet in Boo, tried using it in 2007/early 2008 for testing purposes.

There is an issue logged against this in Boo's codehaus page :
[Boo Issue around this](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/BOO-1004)

Seems like it is scheduled to be fixed in V0.9.3